# Removing a Docker container without using aa-remove-unknown command

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, apparmor

I'm trying to stop the docker container, but I can't because permission is denied

```
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: : permission denied
```

I found the "aa-remove-unknown" command, but I don't think it suits me.
Is it possible to stop the container without this command and without restarting Linux?

For the container, I added the configuration "--privileged".

I will appreciate any hint. Thanks.

Comment: `docker ps` to list all containers and use `docker rm <CONTAINER ID>` to remove it

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to stop the container without this command and without restarting Linux?

If any docker command against that container shows that error (including the `docker rm` command), you can look for the main process that the container is running (for example using `ps` to get `pid`) and `kill <FLAGS> pid` in your machine. Killing the process will probably make the container stop.